# one program(eclipse Mars) need java 8 and one program(console app) need java 7 what to do?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-mars

when I open eclipse Mars it ask for java 8(for JavaFX), and then When I did install java 8u74 now some of my older java app showing that it need java 7(my older installed version). And when I tried to keep both I found some of faculty said to not keeping both. I don't know what to do? Please Kindly help me?

When I open eclipse Now It is showing:
"You are not running your eclipse instance with Java7 or Java8. The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java7/8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java7/8 install."

Comment: why it's necessary to have J8 for eclipse Mars? do you use it in your project? or eclipse doesn't work without it?

Comment: when I use libgdx it assk for java 8

Answer (score 2):

You can try to manually change the Java library for a specific project.

Right click on the project folder, then go to:

```
properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Library
```

and there add the Java 7 library.

If this doesn't work or you don't see the Java 7 library you might need to add some environment variables (e.g. `JAVA_HOME`)

Comment: thanx I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Go to the eclipse installation folder and modify the below property in `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did @Ravi Ranjan But it now shows "adjust eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to java8 install" whenever I open eclipse

Comment: If your Java_Home environment variable is pointing to Java 7, then you can provide the above property. This is the solution to run eclipse with a particular java version. If still facing the error, please paste the exact error.

Comment: "You are not running your eclipse instance with Java7. The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install."<br/> problem is I dont know hwo to -vm

Comment: Try this https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example
Remember that this needs to be set in eclipse.ini